# Magneto 2 - Show related products to mini-cart

Tags: magento2, products, knockoutjs, mini-cart, magento2minicart

Good afternoon everyone,

I am looking to show related products under the products in the Magento2 mini-cart. I have added related products to the product page no problem and added cross sells to the basket page.

I know the mini-cart is driven by js / knockout and I have experience with minor changes to item.html and sub-total.html for visual changes by moving them into my theme but I am not sure how to begin to add the related products under the basket products in the mini-cart.

Any directions or examples on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while, but I did find a way to do what I needed. I used the following UI component example

https://meetanshi.com/blog/show-additional-data-in-magento-2-mini-cart/

I was able to use this UI component example as a frame work and expand it to do what I needed to load / update related products every time a product is added/removed to the cart.